# Unable to download npm package when using vpn

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface, vpn

Any time I try downloading any package from npm (or yarn) while I am connected to a vpn (psiphon in my case) in vscode or my cmd (am using windows 10) it doesn't seem to work and after a while it throws an error like this

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.com/nodemon failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 28
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'`
I
```

**But**

If I disconnect from the vpn everything thing works fine .
And I really need to be connected to the vpn.

Please any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance